# Prepared Statements (MySQLi), Getting Parse Errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm running into several parse errors when I try to run the MySQL query/prepared statement code at the end of this post. Specifically, I'm getting a parse error reading:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in .... on line 22
```

Line 22 corresponds to the end of the first "if" statement. I also got the same error when I had semi-colon at end of first "if" statement (unexpected ';'). When I remove the {, then I get another warning reading:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_REQUIRE_ONCE in ....on line 24
```

Line 24 corresponds to require_once statement. If I put the require statement at the beginning of the code, then I get another parse error:

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ....on line 26
```

Line 26 corresponds to the beginning of the query. So basically unending parse errors. Going a little nuts. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
     <?php

      if (!empty($_POST['var1'])&&!empty($_POST['var2'])
        &&!empty($_POST['var3'])&&isset($_POST['var4'], 
        $_POST['var5'], $_POST['var6']) {

      require_once 'connect.inc.php'; 

      $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6);

      $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
      $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
      $var3 = $_POST['var3'];
      $var4 = $_POST['var4'];
      $var5 = $_POST['var5'];
      $var6 = $_POST['var6'];

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)==1);

      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

      if ($result) {
        echo 'Thank you for your submission.';
        }    
      else {
          echo 'We were unable to process your information.'.mysqli_error($link).'
          Please ensure all required fields were filled out.';
          }

      mysqli_close($link);

 }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Count your parenthesis in the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains

```
  if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)==1);
```

That is basically evaluating the if statement and not doing anything about the result.
So this means your line after

```
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Is always being called. (That's how java would evaluate it atleast, php might error about semicolon directly after if.

Your also missing a closing bracket on your first if statement (as everyone else has noticed).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['var1']) &&
    !empty($_POST['var2']) &&
    !empty($_POST['var3']) &&
    isset($_POST['var4'], $_POST['var5'], $_POST['var6'])
   ) {
```

count your open/close brackets

Answer (score 0):

Line 22:

```
if (!empty($_POST['var1']) &&!empty($_POST['var2']) && !empty($_POST['var3']) && isset($_POST['var4'], $_POST['var5'], $_POST['var6'])) {
```

You missed the closing bracket.